# how to perform edit in mvc contrb grid

Tags: model-view-controller, edit

**hi**,
please tell me how can i perform editing in mvc contrib grid itself without opening a seperate view for that

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You will need to right the javascript to handle that.  Right now the MVC contrib doesn't support in-line editing.  I have been using Telerik's MVC grid which has in-line editing and it works pretty good.  You might want to check that control to see if it will meet you needs.